# How to write a Rails association sort if the records need to be in a specific sequence?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a system sort of like this:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr :name
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tag_associations, dependent:  :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :tag_associations
end
```

There are only 5 tags in the system so far:

```
'Foo'
'Bar'
'Baz'
'Hello'
'World'
```

I want the associated tags on `article.tags` to be in this exact order when they are queried from the database through the association, no matter in what order they were actually inserted into the association. How do you do this the Rails way?

So for example, if we had `[ baz, hello, foo ]`, when we do `article.tags` we should get them in the order `[ foo, baz, hello ]`. If I have to call an extra method or do a scope of some sort that is okay, just wondering the right way to do this sorting.

Comment: What is the determinant of tag order if it isn't alphabetical or creation time?

Comment: Arbitrary order based on product requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's acceptable for the order to be by Tag#id or Tag#created_at, then just set the default scope in the Tag model:

```rb
# in tag.rb

default_scope { order(:id) } # or :created_at, or :name
```

but if you need some special sequence, you'll have to add a `rank` attribute that sets the ordering that you need.

Edit: Here's another approach if you are using mySQL (not available on Postgresql)

```rb
# in tag.rb
SORT_ORDER = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'Hello', 'World']

default_scope { order(Arel.sql("find_in_set(name,'#{SORT_ORDER.join(',')}')")) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add this list as a constant inside your `Article` model and dynamically generate the query:

```rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  TAGS_ORDER = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'Hello', 'World'].freeze

  has_many :tag_associations, dependent:  :destroy
  has_many :tags, -> { order(Article.tags_order_query) }, through: :tag_associations

  def tags_order_query
    return "id" if TAGS_ORDER.blank?

    query = "CASE name"
    query += TAGS_ORDER.each_with_index.map{ |t,i| " WHEN '#{t}' THEN #{i}"}.join
    query += " ELSE #{TAGS_ORDER.length} END, id"
    # generated query will be "CASE name WHEN 'Foo' THEN 0 WHEN 'Bar' THEN 1 WHEN 'Baz' THEN 2 WHEN 'Hello' THEN 3 WHEN 'World' THEN 4 ELSE 5 END, id"
  end
end
```